# How do you create an array-like C# constructor that will allow "new MyClass() { obj1, obj2, obj3 };"

Tags: c#, collections, constructor

I'm trying to create a class that accepts a constructor similar to that of a dictionary, list, or array where you can create the object with a literal collection of objects, though I have been unable to find how to create such a constructor, if it's even possible.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass()
{
    { value1, value2 },
    { value3, value4 }
}
```

Comment: You mean object initializers? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: C# 3 and above have collection initializers that will accomplish this in almost any way imaginable.   I don't understand why you are trying to reinvent something that already exists.

Comment: @Derek Beattie, `collection initializers`, from the same link you referenced.

Comment: @Robert: I presumed that the OP is asking *how* to create a class that can then be initialised using collection initialiser syntax.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, there are tons of reasons to implement a custom collection.  Heck, .NET 4 adds many new collections, so obviously there was lots of room for improvement.  Still is.

Comment: @Samuel: I didn't realize you could do this with your own collections.  I figured it was just built into the compiler.  Pretty neat.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, agreed, it is very neat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need two things to make collection initializers work:

1. Implement `IEnumerable` (non-generic version)
2. `Add()` method that matches the collection initializer

Here's an example that looks like IDictionary:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass()
        {
            {value1, value2},
            {value3, value4}
        };
    }
}

public class MyClass : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(object x, object y)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
    }
}
```

Note that the collection initializer code literally translates to this:

```
MyClass temp = new MyClass();
temp.Add(value1, value2);
temp.Add(value3, value4);
MyClass obj = temp;
```

Because of the temp variable, if any of the `Add()` calls generate an exception, the named variable (`obj` in this case) is never actually assigned.  Interestingly, this also means that if `MyClass` were to implement `IDisposable`, then `Dispose()` would not get called on the constructed object when one of the `Add()` methods generates an error (I tested this to be sure).

Why require `IEnumerable`? Because that interface differentiates classes with `Add` for collections and classes with `Add` for calculations.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx

> [when you analyze classes with `Add`] you realize that there are essentially two fundamentally different meanings of the name “Add”:
>
> a)     Insert the argument into a collection, or
>
> b)     Return the arithmetic sum of the argument and the receiver

Also note that if your collection class implements `IDisposable`, then you should not use collection initializers if there is any chance that `Add()` will throw an exception or if any of the expressions being fed to `Add()` can throw an exception.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/654186/collection-initializers-called-on-collections-that-implement-idisposable-need-to-call-dispose-in-case-of-failure#

Comment: I understand what the code under the `Add` method would look like, but what would the code under `GetEnumerator` look like?   Is it just an ordinary `IEnumerator`?  Is it required to have the same shape as the values in the collection initializer?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, for some reason it's based on the non-generic `IEnumerator` interface and not the generic one.  You really don't even have to impelment `GetEnumerator()` you can just have it `throw new NotImplementedException()` and the collection initializer will still work fine.

Comment: @Robert, @Samuel: if you're interested there's a good discussion of the rationale behind the `IEnumerable`/`Add` requirement here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx

Comment: @LukeH, thanks for that great link.  I've incorporated one quote into my answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

How about a variable constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() {}
    public MyClass(params object[] list) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Isn't the default good enough ?

```
new MyClass {
   MyCol = {Value1, Value2, ... },
};
```